# Does the lie algebra know which lie group elements will commute?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If we have elements in the lie algebra $a, b \in \mathfrak{g}$, when is it true that $\exp(a) \exp(b) = \exp(b) \exp(a)$?

Naively, I believe that if $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent, then their exponentials can commute. I'm not sure how to prove this, however.

In the case of matrix groups, I believe the correct condition is that when $a$ and $b$ commute, then we have that $\exp(a) \exp(b) = \exp(b) \exp(a)$, since the matrices $a, b$ will behave just like real numbers. But this "feels wrong", since I am invoking the *multiplicative* structure of $a$ and $b$. But as elements of the *lie algebra*, all I have is the vector space structure!

I suppose the way to correct this is to use the lie bracket structure, and state that if $[a, b] = 0$, then the exponentials commute? I am still looking for a proof, though. I know a "nuke proof" that [invokes BCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula). If $[X, Y] = 0$, then we can solve for $\exp(a) \exp(b) = exp(z)$, where:

$$
z = a + b + \frac{1}{2}[a, b] + \dots \text{expressions involving }[X, Y] \\
z = a + b + 0 = a + b
$$

So this gives me $\exp(a) \exp(b) = \exp(a + b) = \exp(b + a) = \exp(b) \exp(a)$.

But this is way too much firepower to prove something that feels elementary; BCH is complicated. What is a *simple* proof of the above fact?

Comment: I am not sure whether a Lie algebra has enough conscience to *know* which Lie group elements will commute.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, thank you, I'd missed the question!

Comment: Nevertheless, that was a good question (+1).

Comment: The other question only asks about $\exp(X)$ and $\exp(Y)$ commuting *if* $[X, Y] = 0$ but what about the 'only if' direction? I thought that was also part of the current question too?

Comment: @Vincent That would be appreciated, yes!

Comment: Now that it is closed I can no longer answer, but: being linear independent is not enough. A counterexample is given by the 3-dimensional Heisenberg algebra/group

Comment: So 'only if' might in fact be true, but I'm not 100% sure